# Property 'matSortChange' does not exist on type 'MatSort'

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-cdk

I'm upgrading Angular Material and CDK version 2.0.0-beta.9 to 2.0.0-beta.12 in my Angular 4 app.

I get next compilation error: "Property 'matSortChange' does not exist on type 'MatSort'". Anyone knows whats wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in the changelog, https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md.

**mdSortChange has been renamed to sortChange**